# How do I make an RSS feed using <iframe>?

Tags: html, css, widget, rss, rss-reader

I am still new to coding and I am trying to make my own customizable RSS widget. But having only the URL feed and/or the .xml URL from another server, how do I go about it or what is the best way to get the feed and view it on an iframe of a static page? Here is the code sample that I am trying to view on the static page.

```
<iframe src="https://leaderonomics.com/feed" comp-type="feed" width="400" height="600"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this site? https://rss.bloople.net/
This one is nice too http://www.rssfeedwidget.com/, but I don't know why but the link you are trying to embeed doesn't work in it, even thought RSS is well formed.